# List .txt file (files) with maximum number of lines in a folder and then txt file (files) with minimum number of lines

Tags: powershell

I have this code, but it is not working properly

```
$minLines = 1
$maxLines = 1000
Get-ChildItem . -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse |
    Where-Object {
        $numLines = Get-Content $_.FullName |
            Measure-Object -Line |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lines
        if (($numLines -gt $minLines) -and ($numLines -lt $maxLines)) {
            return $_
        }
    }
```

I have in one directory hundreds of text files some of them has over 700 lines some just 4 or 5. Sometimes min or max criteria meet dozens of files with same number of lines.I would like at first list file or files with minimum number of lines and than file or files(if more than one) with max number of lines.

Probably at first in $minLines and $maxLines shuld be stored somehow maximum and minimum number of lines of all text files of a directory and then list file or files matching minimum number of lines and then maximum number of lines.

I've also find this piece of code:

```
dir . -filter "*.txt" -Recurse -name | foreach{(GC $_).Count} | measure-object -max -min
```

It can by useful too. This code give us information about max and min number of lines in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with something like this one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem . *.txt -Recurse | Select FullName, @{n="NumLines";e={(gc $_).count}} | 
    Sort NumLines | Group NumLines | Select -First 1 -Last 1
```

To see the full names of each file:

```
Get-ChildItem . *.ps1 -Recurse | Select FullName, @{n="NumLines";e={(gc $_).count}} |
    Sort NumLines | Group NumLines | Select -First 1 -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Group
```

Comment: Thank you.This code is really good too.Even show number of lines max and min.I have similar question over here. How to show all these files meeting those criteria (sometimes I have more than dozen) and store the output with all those files in one text files. Sorry because I'm new here I'm not allowed to VOTE UP for those codes.I can only set tick as fully answered.

Answer (score -1):

This will set the min and the max values:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test\ | % {
    $lines = (Get-Content $_.FullName).Count
    if (($min -eq $null) -and ($max -eq $null)) {
        $min=$lines
        $max=$lines
        }
    if ($lines -lt $min) {
        $min=$lines
        }
    if ($lines -gt $max) {
        $max=$lines
        }
    }
```

This will get the files with the maximum number of lines:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test\ | ? {(Get-Content $_.FullName).Count -eq $max}
```

And this will get the files with the minimum:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test\ | ? {(Get-Content $_.FullName).Count -eq $min}
```

If you want the filenames and the number of lines you could append this to the maximum line or modify it slightly to get the minimum:

```
| % {("File " + $_.FullName + " has " + $max + "lines.")}
```

From this you can use `Out-File` to get it to a .txt file.

```
| Out-File C:\max_lines.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Works really  well.I have two small questions. How could each output line show also number of lines of those files and how to store all those files in one text file, because I have dozens of files meeting min or max criteria.So it makes more sense to store it in one file. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want to just see the number of lines in the minimum or maximum you could just output `$min` or `$max`.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question. I just don't know where to put $min or $max so the output would be "Name of File 1" and number of lines "max", next row  "Name of File 2" and number of lines "max".... and then "Name of File 3" and number of lines "min" "Name of File 4" and number of lines "min" ....  The output would be stored in one text file, where one file per row with  "min" or "max" information would be stored.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. I would like to store the output of all max and min files in one text file "minmax.txt"

Comment: Added a bit more that will output those lines to a text file.